# MS Access VBA : Update Loop with multiple IDs

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

I'm kinda stuck on my project.

At the moment I got a form where you can fill in the roster for the players.
It consists of a formation (like 4-3-3) then it will show to positions for the players where you can select a name from a drop down list.

Now I want to add the shirt number as well but i'm getting stuck on that part.
I got no clue of how to update all the players where the MatchID equels the MatchID i'm working on and the PlayerID.
Cause every player has a different shirt number.

```
Option Compare Database
Private Sub Form_Load()
Me.MatchID = Me.OpenArgs
End Sub

'This Sub shows the fields where you can select the players according to the chosen formation.

Private Sub Formation_AfterUpdate()
Dim DefenderLoopVal, MidfielderLoopVal, StrikerLoopVal As String

'Get the formation from the form.
Formation = Me.Formation

'Explode the formation on the - character
FormationExploded = Split(Formation, "-")

'Put the numbers is new variables to use in the Loops.
DefenderLoopVal = FormationExploded(0)
MidfielderLoopVal = FormationExploded(1)
StrikerLoopVal = FormationExploded(2)

'MsgBox DefenderLoopVal
'MsgBox MidfielderLoopVal
'MsgBox StrikerLoopVal

'Make Keeper Visable.
Me.imgKeeper.Visible = True
Me.cbKeeper.Visible = True
Me.NrKeeper.Visible = True

'Make as many textboxes visible as necessary
For i = 1 To DefenderLoopVal
    Form_frmFormation.Controls("cbDefender" & i).Visible = True
    Form_frmFormation.Controls("imgDefender" & i).Visible = True
    Form_frmFormation.Controls("nrDefender" & i).Visible = True
Next

For i = 1 To MidfielderLoopVal
    Form_frmFormation.Controls("cbMidfielder" & i).Visible = True
    Form_frmFormation.Controls("imgMidfielder" & i).Visible = True
    Form_frmFormation.Controls("nrMidfielder" & i).Visible = True
Next

For i = 1 To StrikerLoopVal
    Form_frmFormation.Controls("cbStriker" & i).Visible = True
    Form_frmFormation.Controls("imgStriker" & i).Visible = True
    Form_frmFormation.Controls("nrStriker" & i).Visible = True
Next

End Sub

'This is the actual saving Sub, it will save the players on the according positions
Private Sub Save_Formation_Click()
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset



Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("tblMatchFormation", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)

rs.AddNew
rs!MatchID = Me!MatchID
rs!FormationID = Me!Formation
rs!Keeper = Me!cbKeeper
rs!CenterDefender = Me!cbDefender1
rs!CenterRightDefender = Me!cbDefender2
rs!CenterLeftDefender = Me!cbDefender3
rs!LeftDefender = Me!cbDefender4
rs!RightDefender = Me!cbDefender5
rs!CenterMidfielder = Me!cbMidfielder1
rs!CenterRightMidfielder = Me!cbMidfielder2
rs!CenterLeftMidfielder = Me!cbMidfielder3
rs!LeftMidfielder = Me!cbMidfielder4
rs!RightMidfielder = Me!cbMidfielder5
rs!CenterStriker = Me!cbStriker1
rs!RightStriker = Me!cbStriker2
rs!LeftStriker = Me!cbStriker3
rs.Update

'Should have a update query here that updates the tblMatchPlayer with the numbers according to the MatchID and PlayerID

End Sub
```

But now i want to add the player number as well, the field is on a other table named tblMatchPlayer, all of the Player details are being stored in that table

**TblMatchFormation**

MatchFormationID (AutoNumber)

FormationID (Gets the ID of the Formation that's being played)

MatchID (Gets the ID of the Match)

Keeper (Gets the ID of the player that's a Keeper)

CenterDefender (Gets the ID of the player that's a CenterDefender)

etc.

**tblMatchPlayer**

MatchPlayerID (AutoNumber)

MatchID (Gets the ID of the Match from a previous form)

PlayerID (Gets the ID of the player from a previous form)

Surname (Gets the surname of the player form a previous form)

**ShirtNumber (Should get the number form the form)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL statement to do this, if I understand you correctly, would be:

```
UPDATE tblMatchPlayer SET ShirtNumber = <shirt number>
WHERE MatchID = <matchID> AND PlayerID = <playerID>;
```

or constructing it in VB as:

```
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL= "UPDATE tblMatchPlayer SET ShirtNumber = '" & shirt_number & "' " & _
        "WHERE MatchID = '" & matchID & "' AND PlayerID = '" & playerID &"';"
```

To execute the query:

```
dbs.Execute strSQL
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I need